# Triggering process running in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I wrote a method. I want to print Hi to Toast message if the package I'm giving is running in procces. However, even though the package I have provided is in process, it does not write Hi message. Where did I go wrong? or what am I missing? Your advice important for me!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkServiceRunning(MyService.class);
}
public boolean checkServiceRunning(Class<MyService> myServiceClass){
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
    {
        if ("com.example.processlistener"
                .equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
 }
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
 }
```

Comment: there is no usage of your service class, and `if ("com.example.processlistener"
                .equals(service.service.getClassName()))
        {` what are trying to achieve by this condition?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems here:

1)You never start the service, so of course it isn't running.

2)YOu're comparing a class name to a package name.  That's never going to work.  Your service is named MyService, not processlistener.